# Who should catch exception, the caller or the callee

Tags: c#

I'm currently studying delegates and read this page from codeproject [6 important uses of Delegates and Events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85296/important-uses-of-Delegates-and-Events). I tried to implement the logic of the code in this class.

```
class MathOp
{
    public delegate int OperationsDelegate(int x, int y);
    private OperationsDelegate Del;

    public OperationsDelegate GetDelegate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\tEnter 1 for Addition\n\tEnter 2 for Subtraction\n\tEnter 3 for Multiplication\n\tEnter 4 for Division");
        int input;
        try
        {
            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch(input)
            {
                case 1:
                    Del = Add;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Del = Sub;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Del = Mul;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Del = Div;
                    break;
            }


        }
        catch(FormatException error) { Console.WriteLine(error.Message);  }
        catch(OverflowException error) { Console.WriteLine(error.Message); }
        catch(NullReferenceException error) { Console.WriteLine(error.Message); }

        return Del;
    }


    private int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    private int Sub(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
    private int Mul(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
    private int Div(int a, int b) { return a / b; }            
}
```

Then I called the method from the Main method like:

```
 MathOp Cal = new MathOp();


        try
        {
            int answer = Cal.GetDelegate().Invoke(2, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        }
        catch(FormatException er) { Console.WriteLine(er.Message); }   
        catch(NullReferenceException er) { Console.WriteLine(er.Message); }
```

1. I only added the `try`/`catch` in the `Main` method, because my exception inside the `GetDelegate` was not doing anything. I mean if I step through my code, they are being caught, BUT the program still crashed!!
2. If I go ahead and compile this, I get two errors for entering a letter instead of number. I am expecting only a `FormatException`, but I get both `FormatException` and `NullReferenceException`!

   I thought it is the invoke method but it's not
3. Generally and beyond this code, Am I right in thinking that the burden of catching an exception falls upon the callee method and not the caller?!

Comment: You should only catch exceptions if you know how to handle them.

Comment: In software development it's often not easy (nor sensible) to apply a general rule to every situation... When handling exceptions, ask yourself *"is there something sensible (and safe) I could do here in the event of an exception?"* - if there isn't, then leave the exception for client code to handle.

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
catch(FormatException error) { Console.WriteLine(error.Message);  }
catch(OverflowException error) { Console.WriteLine(error.Message); }
catch(NullReferenceException error) { Console.WriteLine(error.Message); }

return Del;
```

Is causing your problem. You are catching errors before you can actually handle them. When you catch an exception, you are saying "this error is dealt with now, continue as if nothing happened".

So if an error is caught in the above code, you print the error message, then return the delegate, which is still `null` - this causes another error later on.

Since you cannot **meaningfully** handle an exception at this level, you should not catch it there.

Comment: I understand now. So now that an exception has been caught and "handled", what should I do?   I guess that the caller (Main) will have to implement a try/catch block no matter what, right?

Comment: Yes, if main is the first place in the call-stack where you can actually recover - notify the user of the error and ask them to try again, for example.